# É correto omitir a start tag html no HTML5?

Tags: html5

Devemos ou não omitir a start tag html em um documento HTML5? Diversos desenvolvedores ignoram seu uso. Obrigada!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <head>
      <title>...</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Tag html foi omitida!</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "correto"? Se está de acordo com o padrão? Se dá problemas em algum navegador conhecido?

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Sim, também gostaria de saber sobre essas duas perguntas. Obrigada!

Comment: Vou ser sincero, nunca vi ninguém omitir, isso me parece mais um erro. O HTML em navegadores geralmente se não encontra tags como HTML e BODY ele as gera automaticamente. Mas não quer dizer que seja correto, recomendo que se apegue ao básico preferencial e evite seguir códigos que olhou por ae. Muitos desenvolvedores erram, misturam e confundem as cosias (eu já vi cada absurdo), se acha que realmente foi proposital omitir o HTML então forneça um exemplo =)

Comment: O Html5 não removeu a tag html, apenas alguns paramentos, como a declaração  DOCTYPE. DTDs...

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento como exemplo, pode observar o próprio exemplo que está na pergunta: nele a tag <html> não aparece, somente a <!DOCTYPE html>. Seria isso o exemplo que pediu? Obrigada!

Comment: @IngridFarabulini quando pedi um exemplo, me referia a um exemplo real, quero dizer, pra detectar se foi uma falha ou realmente foi proposital. Mas tudo bem vou tentar ver algo sobre isso depois e volto aqui, estou respondendo a sua outra pergunta.

Comment: Mesmo que fosse "possivel" omitir esta tag "start" do html, head, ou mesmo do body, acredito que por convenção, organização e até mesmo a jogada da linguagem de marcação, seja de fato iniciar, e fechar a tag..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O exemplo que citou *me parece mais uma falha*, pode até ser o caso de uma página dinâmica com algum BUG e todos sites que encontrou usam a mesma tecnologia e possuem o mesmo BUG (apesar de passar nos validadores).

Aparentemente como disse o [BrunoBR](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120155/3635) você pode omitir sim a tag `<html>`, eu fiz um teste e também é possível omitir `html`, `head` e `body`, fiz o seguinte teste coloquei isto no *Validate by Direct Input* em http://validator.w3.org:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="...">

<img src="..." alt="...">
```

E validou normalmente, ou seja pra validar aparentemente é permitido sim "omitir" várias tags.

Mas não quer dizer que porque valida que esta correto ou que os navegadores irão processar bem, tags omitidas como `<HTML></HTML>`, `<BODY></BODY>` e `<HEAD></HEAD>` os navegadores quando carregam uma estrutura HTML eles tentam reprocessar elas e assim acabam gerando as tags omitidas, por exemplo, escrever isto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>Test</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link type="text/css" rel="..." href="...">
<img src="" alt="">
```

E o Chrome **reprocessou** assim:

> [image: Chrome]

Internet Explorer 11:

> [image: IE11]

Firefox:

> [image: Firefox]

Em todos testes os motores dos navegadores reprocessaram o HTML, mas quero dizer você pode até omitir e confiar que todos os navegadores irão funcionar (após testes), mas o padrão é criado pra evitar dores de cabeça como obstrução do HTML, as vezes omitir uma tag pode desencadear um problema em outra parte do HTML (por exemplo se a página é dinâmica), cada motor como [Webkit, Blink, Gecko, Trident, EdgeHTML, etc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browser_engines) podem interpretar de maneira variante conforme o conteúdo da página e a ordem dos elementos, o melhor é tentar se apegar ao básico/intermediário e "padronizado", manter o HTML sem omitir tags e de preferencia validar ao máximo que puder o seu HTML.

De maneira alguma omitir tags vai lhe trazer algum beneficio, nem mesmo em consumo ou redução de código.

Existem tags que omitem (na verdade não tem) a tag de fechamento e omitem o `/>` trocando `>` (em HTML apenas), como por exemplo a tag `<link>`, `<meta>` e `<img>` não precisam ser fechadas (em HTML):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="..." href="...">
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="" alt="">
    </body>
</html>
```

Mas quando usamos XHTML (ou XML + HTML, geralmente o mimetype `application/xhtml+xml`) devemos usar assim:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="pt" xml:lang="pt">
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="..." href="..." />
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="" alt="" />
    </body>
</html>
```

> Navegadores mais antigos geralmente requerem `application/xml` como mimetype e o uso de `<?xml ... ?>`

Estes tipos de elementos não precisam de **end tag**, pois são tags do tipo `void` (elemento vazio), ou seja não elas não tem "child" (conteúdo filho com texto ou outras tags): https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element

> Lista de tags `void` do **HTML**:
>
> `area`, `base`, `br`, `col`, `command`, `embed`, `hr`, `img`, `input`, `keygen`, `link`, `meta`, `param`, `source`, `track` e `wbr`

Comment: Eu editei a resposta, não sei se esse era o problema, gostaria que justificasse o problema, ou comentasse se é outro problema na resposta. Obrigado

Comment: Nossa não sabia que as end tags também podem ser omitidas. Isso eu não tinha visto em lugar algum também..

Comment: É uma boa resposta, só acho a parte sobre xhtml e fechamento de void tags é desnecessária (começando no parágrafo "Existem tags que omitem ..."), fugiu do escopo da questão. E não fui eu que downvotei, sua resposta está correta contudo como eu disse só acho que você estendeu ela demais (apenas minha opinião).

Comment: @BrunoRB não é que fugiu ao escopo da pergunta, é que amarrou um assunto no outro, se notar várias respostas aqui no site costumamos colocar "extras", isso é opcional e totalmente pessoal de se fazer. Eu mesmo faço muito isso, é como se fossem dicas.

Comment: @IngridFarabulini sim, foi um teste que notei a pouco, todas puderam ser omitidas `<html>`, `</html>`, `<head>`, `</head>`, `<body>` e `</body>`. Mas é importante tomar cuidado, já que eventualmente podem ocorrer falhas de obstrução do HTML, acho melhor se manter no padrão =)

Comment: Só para acrescentar: o Chrome fez a parte dele e adicionou as tags mantendo o padrão, mas o IE não. Isso, claro, observando o código com CTRL+U. Pode até ser que internamente o IE também faça o que o Chrome fez... obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: @IngridFarabulini acredito que no Ctrl+U realmente não de pra observar isto, mas no Inspetor de elementos vai notar que funciona, editei a resposta e adicionei alguns detalhes. Mesmo "funcionando" com a omissão de tags eu recomendo que evite isto pois  cada motor como Webkit, Blink, Gecko, Trident, etc podem interpretar de maneira variante conforme o conteúdo da página e a ordem dos elementos.

Answer (score 5):

Curiosamente é sim válido, como você pode ver na própria [especificação da w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/html.html#html-tags) a abertura da tag pode ser omitida **desde que a primeira coisa dentro do escopo da html tag não seja um comentário**, assim o exemplo que você usou na questão pode ser considerado correto, contudo o seguinte não seria:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <!-- Este HTML é inválido segundo a especificação oficial para HTML5 -->
   <head>
      <title>...</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Tag html foi omitida!</p>
   </body>
 </html>
```

O fato de ser válido não quer dizer que você deva fazer, teoricamente é ok contudo você não pode assumir que os todos os browsers implementem a especificação definida pela w3c a risca (e na verdade nenhum deles implementa, todos tem incosistências aqui e ali), assim fazendo isso você está correndo o risco de seu HTML não renderizar corretamenta em algum deles. No fim também a não ser que você esteja fazendo a front page da google o ganho é nulo, você vai economizar algo como 20~ bytes de banda do usuário, essa otimização não vale nem o tempo que você gastou escrevendo a pergunta ;)

Comment: O problema do comentário, é que ao se montar o DOM, o `html` implícito acaba ficando depois do comentário, desestruturando a página. Mesma coisa na tag de fechamento, se o documento contiver um `body`

Answer (score 2):

Não que seja correto ou incorreto, mas é válido e inclusive recomendado com finalidade de reduzir a quantidade de códigos.

Pode-se omitir até mesmo a tag `<body>`.

Mas isso é um assunto controverso e confuso.

Até pouco antes do advento do HTML5, por exemplo, era recomendado especificar certos parâmetros:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"
  type="text/css">
```

Hoje, a recomendação é de que podemos omitir o atributo `type`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Para esse exemplo espcífico do CSS, é compreensível e faz sentido, pois o atributo `rel="stylesheet"` já define o que é o documento, tornando o atributo `type"text/css"` redundante.

A confusão e controvérsia se dá pelo fato de que até então o recomendado era sempre especificar o atributo `type` pois em versões mais antigas de browsers poderia causar conflitos e má interpretação.

## Um exemplo mais específico que causava conflitos:

**Carregando arquivo JavaScript**

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

**Carregando arquivo VBScript**

```
 <script src="script.vbs"></script>
```

Isso é um exemplo clássico que forçou a recomendação da definição do atributo `type`. Além do atributo `type`, tínhamos que especificar também o atributo `language`:

```
<script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript" src="script.vbs"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

Por volta de 2004, começaram as recomendações de que não era mais necessário especificar o atributo `language`, e utilizar o atributo `type`. Então, desde essa época, gradualmente esse atributo na tag `<script>` foi sendo esquecido. Hoje é muito raro encontrar. Normalmente encontra-se em sistemas antigos.

## Mudanças periódicas nos padrões e recomendações

Os padrões e recomendações mudam periodicamente. Por via das dúvidas mantenha a semântica clássica.

Para uma maior referência sobre o assunto, veja esse guia do Google, referente as recomendações atuais para HTML5. https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.xml#Optional_Tags

Apenas não confunda pois isso é para HTML5 somente. Evite tal prática para um ambiente onde o usuário poderá acessar usando navegadores mais antigos.

## Tolerância para erros de semântica

O lado "cômico" disso é que apesar de ser inválido em versões de browsers mais antigos, é tolerável.

Mesmo em browsers antigos, pode-se omitir tags como `<html>` e `<head>` pois em determinada época, tais browsers passaram a "tolerar" alguns erros na semântica tendo em vista que muitos sites possuíam erros considerados toleráveis, isso foi então implementado nos browsers e persiste até hoje.

## Document type definition

Note que isso tudo também depende da definição do ***W3C//DTD*** da página:  https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html, o qual não influencia somente no HTML mas também no CSS e JavaScript.

Comment: Fiquei confuso. Pra mim, omitir esse elemento, ou o body, ou o head, é inválido - ainda que tolerado pelos browsers. Acredito que os validadores concordem comigo :)

Comment: Exato. É inválido, porém tolerável. Particularmente ainda prefiro manter o uso clássico `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`. Posso até omitir a tag `<head>` pois na prática não serve para nada. Mas a tag `<body>`, acho inseguro omitir pois muitos parseadores de HTML procuram a tag `<body>`.

Comment: É que parece que você diz que tudo bem omitir. Não é porque os browsers toleram que nós também devemos tolerar.

Comment: Não fui eu que dei o downvote. Também tomei um -1 :/ --- Seria interessante se justificassem os downvotes. Paciência.

Comment: @bfavaretto: O padrão html5 foi basicamente criado para por no papel a forma com que os browsers se comportavam na prática. Todo aquele html "inválido" mas que era tolerado por todos os browsers na prática passou a fazer parte oficial do html daqui pra frente.

Comment: @DanielOmine: Na sua resposta você menciona DTDs mas, na prática, os browsers ignoram completamente o DTD que aparece nos doctypes. A única coisa que eles fazem é ver se tem um doctype no documento ou não (a ausência de doctype aciona o *quirks mode*, para compatibilidade com webpages dos anos 90). Tanto é que a recomendação hoje em dia (segundo html5) é só escrever `<!doctype html>`. Essa sintaxe simplificada pro doctype foi escolhida porque ela já é o suficiente pra fazer os browsers antigões evitarem de usar o quirks mode.