# CSS renderiza tag BODY mesmo sem a TAG existir

Tags: html, css

Tenho um arquivo HTML no qual defini do seguinte modo

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Prompt</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/prompt.css" type="text/css">
    </head>
</html>
```

No meu arquivo **prompt.css** estilizei da seguinte maneira

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;} 

body{
    background:#000;
}
```

Como resultado, o navegador interpretou que a TAG BODY existia e deixou o background em PRETO, como definido no css.

A questão é, por que isso aconteceu ?

Comment: Qual é a ideia de ter uma página HTML sem a tag `<body>`?

Comment: Não é uma ideia, acontece que eu esqueci de colocá-lo. Dai então surgiu a dúvida.

Comment: Os navegadores atuais já adicionam por padrão a tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mesmo que não adicione a tag `<body>` o navegador tenta preencher o que falta do documento, ou seja mesmo que eu faça apenas isto no HTML:

```
<p>teste</p>
```

Vai ser gerado algo como (sem doctype):

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p>teste</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Talvez você não tenha notado o `<body>`, porque quando usamos o *doctype* do HTML5 a altura do `<body>` padrão será zero, então basta adicionar um `height: 100%` que vai notar que o `<body>` foi sim gerado:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        body {
            background-color: #f00;
            height: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
</html>
```

Veja o resultado:

[image: Resultado]

> O teste foi no Opera, mas ele usa a mesma tecnologia do Chrome para renderização

Eu respondi uma pergunta semelhante a esta que falava sobre omitir as tags:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/120146/3635

Comment: Legal. Interessante saber que o navegador influencia diretamente no código.

Comment: @MauroAlexandre acredito que desde o IE5.5 e Mozilla Firefox 1 isso já ocorria, então todos navegadores fazem isto, não será algo para se preocupar ;)

Comment: Quando eu programava no netscape , nas suas primeiras versões, nunca tinha ocorrido isso, de lá pra cá nunca mais ocorreu, dai resolvi tirar a dúvida.